# How do I finish mission 5 in Devil May Cry 3?

Tags: devil-may-cry-3

So, I got to mission 5, I beat the Centipede and the Joker, but I can't figure out the thing with the floors. I don't know what to do. Can you explain to me how I can complete this mission? I've been trying for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Move foward to the red door on the floor. After killing Centipede it should be opened and when you pick up artifact it will start movie and level ends.